# MySQL MERGE table across separate databases

Tags: mysql, database

I have a database **db1** which contains tables **tbl1**, **tbl2**, and **tbl3**.

I also have an empty database **db2**.

Can I create a MERGE table **mrg1** which merges the contents of **tbl1**, **tbl2**, and **tbl3** from database **db1**, but is stored in database **db2**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if your database is set up to allow you to run queries against multiple databases at once. I think it would look something like this,

```
INSERT INTO db2.mrg1 (colA,colB,ColC)
(
  SELECT colA,colB,ColC
  FROM db1.tbl1,db1.tbl2,db1.tbl3
  WHERE [whatever joins your tables together]
)
```